# Sharing internet from Macbook Pro has a 5 device limit?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi, internet-sharing

I'm trying to share the (wifi) internet connection from a 2019 Macbook Pro 15-inch on OSX version 10.14.6 (18G1012) using a USB Ethernet connector and the device's built-in WiFi chipset as my "router". The first 5 devices all work, (2 iPhones, a PS4, an iPad, a 2015 Macbook Pro on 10.15), but as soon as I connect any other device I have (Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, 2013 Macbook Pro) they all will predictably fail with a generic error message that can basically be summed up as "can't connect" and will re-prompt for the Wi-Fi password. I'm sharing my USB Ethernet adapter's connection like:
[image: Internet Sharing Settings]

If I power toggle the Wi-Fi shared connection and boot everybody off, if I pick a device that formally failed to connect before the others, it'll work until there are 5 devices connected, and device #6 and beyond will always fail. Even if it previously had known the network! If I turn a device's WiFi that's currently connected off, a failed device will connect. It's pretty clear there's a 5 device limit on the sharing laptop.

I've done some research and it seems that others have no problem connecting more than 5 devices to a Macbook's wifi, so what am I doing wrong? Are they not connecting simultaneously like I am? I'm not afraid of terminal or gathering more information, but I'm not sure where to even start with this. The sharing screen isn't terribly verbose.